# $\Delta x$ and $\Delta k$ for purely harmonic wave

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

For a purely harmonic wave, composed of a single frequency/ wavelength. Within the context of Fourier analysis, what are $\Delta x$ and $\Delta k$ (corresponding to the shape of wave packets) equivalent to, generally speaking? I know that $\Delta x \Delta k$~ $1$, but I'm not sure how to represent each of these terms individually.

Comment: Can you give more context and explanation? What does your notation represent?

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta x$ is the square root of the variance of $x$, and similarly for $\Delta k$. Explicitly
\begin{align}
\Delta x &= \sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle - \langle x\rangle^2}\\
\Delta k &= \sqrt{\langle k^2\rangle - \langle k\rangle^2}
\end{align}

where
\begin{align}
\langle x \rangle = \int_{\mathbf{R}} x\, |\psi(x)|^2\, dx\\
\langle k \rangle = \int_{\mathbf{R}} k\, |\hat\psi(k)|^2\, dk
\end{align}
and similarly for the expectation of the squares.

For a harmonic wave, $\psi(x) = e^{-i q x}$ and $\hat\psi(k) = \sqrt{2\pi}\,\delta(k - q)$. In this case, $\Delta x$ is infinite and $\Delta k$ is 0.

The uncertainty principle holds for Schwartz functions, which the harmonic wave is not, so it's not a problem that uncertainty doesn't strictly hold for this case.

Note that this example does comport with the hand-waving, intuitive uncertainty principle as physicists use it: if you have a harmonic wave, you know $k$ exactly, so there's no uncertainty in $k$ and $x$ must be completely undetermined.

For more details, see: Stein and Shakarchi, *Fourier Analysis*, $\S$5.4

Comment: For more physics hand-waving it may be worth pointing out that one can consider a wave with a Gaussian envelope of $\sigma_x$ in which case $\Delta x \propto \sigma_x$ and $\Delta_k \propto \frac{1}{\sigma_x}$. Then as we take $\sigma_x\rightarrow \infty$ (approximating a plane wave) we see $\Delta_x \rightarrow \infty$ and $\Delta_k \rightarrow 0$. Of course if one truly wants a plane wave you have nicely pointed out the problems with not having a Schwartz function.